# Android Layout with height in percent

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make layout like that:

[image]

But I don't know how to make panel 2 and 3 filling remaining space (after adding fixed size panel 1) in 50:50 ratio. There must be something I am missing or just don't know about Android layout, but what is it?

I forgot to mention that I want to use Constraint Layout for these panels. I use Android Studio.

Comment: add some code here what u tried

Comment: use a Linear layout and give how much space you want to panel 1 and then give weight = 1 to the other panel 2 or 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a LinearLayout and layout_weight

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_height="16dp" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/red"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The Views can be changed to ConstraintLayouts

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/panel1Layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/otherPanelContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/panel1Layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/panel2Layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/panel3Layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```